# Why the code works only on Chrome but not of Firefox/Waterfox despite no errors in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, skeleton-code

Created a mini interactive video module based on a tutorial but weirdly enough, the code works on Chrome but not on firefox or Waterfox.. Can anyone figure out what's wrong?

In this project, the video gets paused & resumed at several specific time intervals to wait for user input. The pausing and resuming works on Chrome but firefox doesnt seem to register anything.

Also, during development when it did work, the timeupdate paused the video at different intervals on firefox than it did on chrome.

```
// Various variables
var videoHalfWay = 0;
var formattedHalfWay = 0;

// Choice parts
var choiceHeart = 2;
var partnerPart = 56;
var partnerChosen = false;
var badChoicePart = 15;       // Modified
var ending = 20;              // ADDED
var goodChoiceChosen = false;
var choiceHeartchosen = false;
var qualityChosen = false;
var costChosen = false;
var qualityQuestion = 30;
var costPart = 38;
var costCons = 36;

// Question variable
var question1Asked = false;

var video1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.featherlight.defaults.afterClose = playPauseVideo;

    video1 = $('#video1');

    $('.box1').on('click', function(){
        choiceHeartchosen = true;
        video1[0].play();
    });

    $('.box2').on('click', function(){

        partnerChosen = true;
        video1[0].currentTime = partnerPart;
        video1[0].play();
    });

    $('.box3').on('click', function(){ //quality
        costChosen = true;
        video1[0].currentTime = costPart;
        video1[0].play();
    });

    $('.box4').on('click', function(){ //cost
        qualityChosen = true;
        video1[0].play();

    });



    $(video1).on('loadeddata', function(){
        videoHalfWay = Math.round(this.duration/2);
    })


    $(video1).on('timeupdate', function(){

         console.log(this.currentTime);

        var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime*100)/100;
        console.log(currentTime);
        var durationNum = Math.round(this.duration*100)/100;
        var formattedCurrentTime = secondsToHms(currentTime);
        var formattedDurationTime = secondsToHms(durationNum)
        onTrackedVideoFram(formattedCurrentTime, formattedDurationTime)

        if(currentTime >2){ $(".box1, .box2").hide(); }

        if(currentTime <20){ $(".box4").hide(); }
        if(currentTime <22){ $(".box3").hide(); }

        if(currentTime >20){ $(".box4").show(); }
        if(currentTime >21){ $(".box3").show(); }

        if(currentTime >30){ $(".box3, .box4").hide(); }

        if(currentTime == costCons && costChosen == true){  video1[0].pause(); }

        if(currentTime == choiceHeart && choiceHeartchosen == false){

            video1[0].pause();

        }

        if(currentTime == costCons && costChosen == false){

            video1[0].pause(); //Pauses for Cost Consequence

        }

        if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && qualityChosen == false){

            video1[0].pause(); //Pauses the video at 30

        }


        if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && costChosen == true){

            video1[0].play(); //Plays Consequence for Cost Effective choice

        }




        if(currentTime == videoHalfWay){
            // Halfway point
        }

        if(currentTime == durationNum){
            // Video complete
        }

    });

});

function onTrackedVideoFram(curretTime, duration){
    $('.current').text(curretTime);
    $('.duration').text(duration);
}

function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
}

function playPauseVideo(popUp){
    if(video1[0].paused){
        video1[0].play();
    } else{
        video1[0].pause();
        $.featherlight($(popUp));
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the entire project :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssxvrvrfwu5izss/Webmodule.rar?dl=0

Would appreciate if someone could help me here or one on one..

Comment: Please describe what is not working? A little more detail would be helpful.
Have you tried debugging your JS in FF?

Comment: The video gets paused at several time intervals to wait for user input. 
The pausing and resuming works on Chrome but firefox doesnt seem to register anything.

Comment: @Logan are you sure you want to make your hard work public? Instead try to debug slightly if your functions that are being called in chrome are also being called in firefox. Once you find that, submit that code and we could help you out.

Comment: Dont worry about it. I have only tweaked the code in the last 2 - 3 days the code is part of a free tutorial available online. 
And even if it was my own "hard work" if I made it public then I must have already thought about it.

Comment: Also, I am like, VERY new to this, could you explain better about what you meant by if my functions are being called? How do I do that?

Comment: @Logan press F12 in Firefox and find your way to the Debugger tab. You can add breakpoints and trace the flow of your code